# Ошибка ERROR: Couldn't determine iptables version при настройке брандмауэра и установке nginx в debian

Tags: linux, nginx, debian, ufw

начал разбираться с debian и nginx. Необходимо поставить nginx на debian WSL. Скачал debian c Microsoft Store. Список команд, которые были прописаны: sudo apt update,
sudo apt install nginx,apt install ufw. При открытии списка профилей ufw командой sudo ufw app list возникает ошибка 'ERROR: Couldn't determine iptables version'

Answer (score 1):

Не устанавливай ufw на виндовс, пропусти команды связанные с ним. На Виндовс придётся настраивать бренмауер виндовса.

Comment: А как поставить? Ставил по этому гайду https://www.8host.com/blog/ustanovka-nginx-v-debian-10/ . Мне необходимо поставить nginx на WSL debian

Comment: @Илья `apt install nginx` и все

Comment: При запросе состояние в системе инцилизации командой apt install nginx выдает ошибку 'System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
Failed to connect to bus: Host is down'

Comment: @Илья тут ещё инит надо отключить. Зачем вам демоны в wsl? Нгингкс есть виндовый, а если нужно для обучения, то поставьте дебиан на виртуалку. Там и фаер запустится и инит.

Comment: Передо мной стоит определённая задача. Мне необходимо поставить WSL debian. Я скачал debian из Microsoft Store. Далее необходимо поставить nginx. Изучил множество разных гайдов и везде у меня ошибки.  Далее у меня будет приложение на django

Answer (score 1):

После установки Debian в его окружении создай файл `/usr/sbin/policy-rc.d`

```
#!/bin/sh
exit 101
```

и сделай его исполнимым `chmod +x /usr/sbin/policy-rc.d`. Этот скрипт скажет установщику не запускать службы.

Потом установка

```
sudo apt install nginx
```

Чтоб запустить web сервер напишите просто `sudo nginx`. Остановить `sudo nginx -s quit`. А service, systemctl и прочее не работает в wsl.

Comment: Большое вам спасибо. Сделал всё как вы сказали и всё поставилось без ошибок. Как мне теперь проверить его работоспособность? Читал, что можно через service и systemctl, но вы мне сказали, что это тут не работает

Comment: @Илья предпоследняя строчка

Comment: Я так понимаю вы про sudo nginx?

Comment: да, запустите  и увидите его в процессах и страничку в браузере